# Symfony 5.4 profilerlistener takes a long time on each request

Tags: performance, symfony, symfony5

I have just started a new symfony project with the --web-app command to install all relevant bundles for starting a web application. After creating some controllers I noticed that each request takes a few seconds (which it never dit in previous new projects).
It seems that the profilerlistener is doing something strange in combination with Doctrine. (see profiler screenshot attachment).

Any help on figuring out what is causing the delay?
It isn't the query itself...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever stumbles on this issue, I have found the problem;
It turns out that the doctrine migrations version I am using (3.2.1) has something weird in the profiling that takes a long time each request. If you set `enable_profiler: false` in the doctrine_migrations.yaml things should be normal.